# AWS API Gateway infront of AWS ALB (Ingress Controller) for EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

I am trying to understand the use of API Gateway along with AWS ALB (Ingress Controller) for the EKS cluster.

Let's say,
there are 10 microservices in the AWS EKS cluster running on 10 pods. The EKS cluster is in Private VPC.
I can create Kubernetes Ingress which will create an ALB and provide rule-based routing. The ALB will be in Public VPC and I believe, AWS will allocate a public ip to the ALB. I can configure the ALB behind Route53 to access using the domain name. My understanding says that ALB supports multiple features including host or path based routing, TLS (Transport Layer Security) termination, WebSockets, HTTP/2, AWS WAF (Web Application Firewall) integration, integrated access logs, and health checks.

So, security wise there should not be any challenge. **Am I wrong?**

Please refer [Link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/kubernetes-ingress-aws-alb-ingress-controller/#:%7E:text=ALB%20supports%20multiple%20features%20including,access%20logs%2C%20and%20health%20checks.) of the above mentioned solution architecture.

1. **Is there any specific use case where I need to use AWS API Gateway in front of AWS ALB in the above-mentioned architecture?**
2. **What are additional benefits the AWS API Gateway has along with AWS ALB?**
3. **Should I put AWS ALB in the Private VPC if decided to use AWS API Gateway in front of that?**

Answer (score 2):

With API GW you will get rate limiting, throttling and if you want to authenticate and authorize requests based on OAUTH or any other auth model that can be done with API GW.